# AWS Glue - Read all objects in an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I wanted to check whether it is a good idea to read all objects in an Amazon  S3 buckets with Glue. The process flow is as follows:

1. Files Arrive in S3 Bucket
2. File name needs to be added as a new column
3. Load data to RDS

This will be a scheduled batch job

Appreciate the help.

Comment: all files has the same schema? with JSON-Line files, AWS Glue creates one table for each file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the files. These are structured data CSV files.

Comment: which RDS are you using, if its Aurora, they have a feature to load data directly from S3,which I have implemented successfully, and I see it much faster as well. Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link if you are using RDS Aurora : [load from S3 to Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html).  After all configurations in RDS Aurora parameter group as per the document, write a python script using python mysql connector library, and run the mysql command "Load data from S3//....".  Please add required ETL sections for adding columns for file name.

```
cur, conn = connect()
loadQry = "LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://<bucket-name>/<part name>' REPLACE INTO TABLE <dbname.tablename> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5) SET FIELD1 = @var1, FIELD2 = @var2, FIELD3 = @var3, FIELD4 =@var4, FIELD5=@var5;"
cur.execute(loadQry)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule Glue `crawler` to craw the schema into Glue datalog, which solves the problem that you don't have control over the files.

If by `File name needs to be added as a new column` you mean that each new file should be added to an existing table, maybe Glue is better at aggregating the new file with existing data.

Comment: Crawler method works to identify schema. I have tested that successfully. Filename has a certain set of data attributes. These attributes need to be made a part of the data (these columns are not part of the file data structure) . Example : File name: NEWYORK_2018.csv Data Structure: "Pincode, Population". Expected Target data structure:" City,Year, Pincode, population"